# Is it possible to call the same method on different object types of same parent class with an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

Due to a homework assignment that is supposed to test our understanding of inheritance, I have many different subclasses that all end up with the same instance variables. In each of these subclasses, I have a method `printInfo()` that prints all of the instance variables. `printInfo()` is exactly the same in every class it exists in, but I'm fairly sure that I can't move it to any of the parent classes because some of the instance variables only exist within that child class (aka the class that also contains `printInfo()`). From what I read, I can create an ArrayList that contains every object by using the parent class like this:

```
ArrayList<Parent> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Parent>;
myArrayList.add(new Child1());
myArrayList.add(new Child2());
```

My problem is that I want to be able to call `printInfo()` on each object in this ArrayList. I tried to use a for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); ++i) {
    myArrayList.get(i).printInfo();
}
```

but it won't recognize my `printInfo()` method because it only exists in the subclasses and not the parent class that the ArrayList uses. I'm assuming this is because the ArrayList contains objects of the Parent class so it won't call any member functions of the child class. Is there any way that I can call the `printInfo()` method using an ArrayList (or a similar data structure)?

**NOTE:** I'm aware that this program is poorly designed considering that there are multiple subclasses with identical methods, but I have been told this is exactly what is expected from the assignment. I don't need advice on how to restructure the classes, I'm only interested in finding a way to call the same method efficiently on multiple objects of different classes.

Comment: I also doubt the assignment is poorly designed. It's probably meant to teach you about inheritance.

Comment: I think that having to reuse identical code in multiple classes for the sole purpose of using inheritance instead of structuring an easily readable and maintainable program using more applicable tactics is a poorly designed assignment.

Comment: It's not clear what you've duplicated. If you have in fact copied code yourself, then sure, you can combine "shared" instance variables into a common class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In each of these subclasses, I have a method printInfo() that prints all of the instance variables. printInfo() is exactly the same in every class it exists in

Seems okay

> but I'm fairly sure that I can't move it to any of the parent classes because some of the instance variables only exist within that child class (aka the class that also contains printInfo()).

You can move the method, though. You need to **override** it in each of the children. It doesn't matter if some variables don't exist in the parent, just print the variables you do have. The contents of the methods are intended to be different. That's the assignment - to understand inheritance and method overriding.

If you need to print the parents variables, you can call `super.printInfo()` in the Child classes.

For example, if both the parent and child have some instance variable of the same name, then the child class is "shadowing" the variable of the parent. Should be no need to copy anything.

> but it won't recognize my printInfo() method.

Once you implement the method on the Parent class, it will. Once you have an object that extends the Parent, then it will call the overridden method.

> because it only exists in the subclasses and not the parent class that the ArrayList uses

Let's say you couldn't move the method for whatever reason... I suppose you could do this. Not sure, though. I've been bad at messing with inheritance like this because I've haven't had much experience with these designs.

```
Parent p = myArrayList.get(i);
if (p instanceof Child1) {
    ((Child1) p).printInfo();
}
```

Comment: @comp1020comp: and cricket's and my answers are the same. Give the parent class a `printInfo()` method, and override it in the child classes that need it to be overridden. Period. End of story. Full stop.

Comment: Defining the method in the parent class and overriding it in each subsequent subclass worked perfectly so I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way that I can call the printInfo() method using an ArrayList (or a similar data structure)?

Only if the parent class or interface has the `printInfo()` method. Note that even if the parent class has a `printInfo()` method, each child class can override this, and print its own variables in the method. Often such a method will first call the parent's super method before calling its own variable.

For example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ParentChild {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Parent> parentList = new ArrayList<>();
        parentList.add(new Parent());
        parentList.add(new Child1());

        for (Parent obj : parentList) {
            obj.printInfo();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Parent {
    private int a = 0;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.print("a: " + a);
    }
}
```

```
class Child1 extends Parent {
    private int b = 2;

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void printInfo() {
        super.printInfo();
        System.out.println("; b: " + b);
    }
}
```